# Aligning subplots horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working with the gapminder dataset (a pandas dataframe) that looks something like this:
[image]

Currently, I can make a plot of life expectancy against years using groupby() and apply() for each of the 5 continents. However, they're all vertically aligned. Here's what they look like (Missing Oceania and Europe):
[image]

Does anyone have any leads on how to make the plots horizontally aligned like this?
[image]

I probably need to create 5 subplots, but I don't know how I can use groupby() and apply() in that case.

Much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You will find it well explained [here in the matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) including ax-sharing examples.

Comment: It will be much easier to show an accurate solution if you include some reproducible data.  Images of dataframes aren't useful here.

Comment: Another way to arrange subplots in this duplicate: [Arrange two plots horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071052/arrange-two-plots-horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

Use **subplots**:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,5,sharey='row') # nrows, ncols you need 5 columns
```

Then plot using you got: