# pandas data frame plotting in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have the following pandas data frame and would like to create `n` plots horizontally where n = unique labels(l1,l2,.) in the `a1 row`(for example in the following example there will be two plots because of `l1 and l2`). Then for these two plots, each plot will plot `a4` as the x-axis against `a3` as y axis. For example, `ax[0]` will contain a graph for `a1`, where it has three lines, linking the points `[(1,15)(2,20)],[(1,17)(2,19)],[(1,23)(2,15)]` for the below data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    d = {'a1': ['l1','l1','l1','l1','l1','l1','l2','l2','l2','l2','l2','l2'],
         'a2': ['a', 'a', 'b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f'],
         'a3': [15,20,17,19,23,15,22,21,23,23,24,27],
         'a4': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]}
    
    df=pd.DataFrame(d)
    df
    a1  a2  a3  a4
    1   a   15  1 
    1   a   20  2
    1   b   17  1
    1   b   19  2
    1   c   23  1
    1   c   15  2
    2   d   22  1
    2   d   21  2
    2   e   23  1
    2   e   23  2
    2   f   24  1
    2   f   27  2
```

I currently have the following:

```
def graph(dataframe):
    x = dataframe["a4"]
    y = dataframe["a3"]
    ax[0].plot(x,y) #how do I plot and set the title for each group in their respective subplot without the use of for-loop?
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,len(pd.unique(df["a1"])),sharey='row',figsize=(15,2))
df.groupby(["a1"]).apply(graph)
```

However, my above attempt only plots all a3 against a4 on the first subplot(because I wrote `ax[0].plot()`). I can always use a for-loop to accomplish the desired task, but for large number of unique groups in `a1`, it will be computationally expensive. Is there a way to make it a one-liner on the line `ax[0].plot(x,y)` and it accomplishes the desired task without a for loop? Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby(["a1"]).plot(x='a4', y='a3', subplots=True)`

Comment: @PaulH I tried this approach before but it displays the graphs vertically stacked(I would like them horizontally stack and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071052/arrange-two-plots-horizontally) recommends me to use `subplots` instead of `pandas.plot()`

Comment: @JayEstrera you can add `layout=(1,2)` to get them to plot horizontally

Comment: @a11 I believe in this case, `layout=(1,2)` only stretch or compress the graph, not aligning them horizontally

Comment: Ok it works when I store information of each group of a1 and their respective indices into a dictionary, `ax[dict.get(pd.unique(dataframe["a1"])[0])].plot(x,y)` gets me the desired result

Comment: @PaulH `df.groupby(["a1"]).plot(x='a4', y='a3', subplots=True)` is popping up two figure windows for me for some weird reason

Comment: @a11 You've created a figure and axes with `plt.subplots`, and then the dataframe's plot method is creating another set. You can drop the call to `plt.subplots` or pass the axes objects to the dataframe`a plot method

Comment: @PaulH yes, I dropped that; code is just `df=pd.DataFrame(d)` ... `df.groupby(["a1"]).plot(x='a4', y='a3', subplots=True)` ... `plt.show()`  and it pops up two figure windows. This isn't even my OP, but I did not know about Pandas plotting capabilities, so I am keen to figure out this shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any way of avoiding a for loop when plotting this data with pandas. My initial thought was to reshape the dataframe to make `subplots=True` work, like this:

```
dfp = df.pivot(columns='a1').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
dfp
```

[image: df_pivoted]

But I do not see how to select the level 1 of the the columns `MultiIndex` to make something like `dfp.plot(x='a4', y='a3', subplots=True)` work.

Removing level 0 and then running the plotting function with
`dfp.droplevel(axis=1, level=0).plot(x='a4', y='a3', subplots=True)` raises `ValueError: x must be a label or position`. And even if this worked, there would still be the issue of linking the correct points together.

The [seaborn package](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) was created to conveniently plot this kind of dataset. If you are open to using it here is an example with [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd    # v 1.1.3
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.0

d = {'a1': ['l1','l1','l1','l1','l1','l1','l2','l2','l2','l2','l2','l2'],
     'a2': ['a', 'a', 'b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f'],
     'a3': [15,20,17,19,23,15,22,21,23,23,24,27],
     'a4': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sns.relplot(data=df, x='a4', y='a3', col='a1', hue ='a2', kind='line', height=4)
```

[image: relplot]

You can customize the colors with the `palette` argument and adjust the grid layout with `col_wrap`.